# how can I have a public method only show up when the template has a specific type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template that is intended to take int, float, double, char and std::string.
I want a method to only exist if the template typename is `std::string`

Is this possible?

Comment: `std::enable_if` might come in Handy for such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use C++20, you can use a `requires` expression on the desired method to cause it to only be available under certain circumstances.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <concepts>

template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    void alwaysAvailable() { std::cout << "Always available\n"; }

    void conditionallyAvailable() requires std::same_as<T, std::string>
    {
        std::cout << "T is std::string\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> fooInt;
    fooInt.alwaysAvailable();
    //fooInt.conditionallyAvailable(); // Constraint not satisfied

    Foo<std::string> fooString;
    fooString.alwaysAvailable();
    fooString.conditionallyAvailable();
}
```

`Foo<T>::alwaysAvailable` is, as the name suggests, always available no matter what `T` is. `Foo<T>::conditionallyAvailable` is only available when `T` is `std::string`.

[Demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/PhE7joxxb)

The C++17 version is a little uglier. We have to make `conditionallyAvailable` a method template and then place some SFINAE constraints on the method:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    void alwaysAvailable() { std::cout << "Always available\n"; }

    template<class U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, T> && std::is_same_v<U, std::string>, void> conditionallyAvailable()
    {
        std::cout << "T is std::string\n";
    }
};
```

[Demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/o79hnET8Y)

C++14 and C++11 versions are similar to the C++17 version, except for needing to expand out `enable_if_t` and `is_same_v`.

Answer (score 0):

Use SFINAE  along with type traits to achieve such kind of feature. Compiler will simply discard the other
candidate function . Since C++11 enable_if is a wrapper on top of SFINAE , If you have access to C++11 and beyond support , you can directly use enable_if

Comment: `enable_if` has been present since C++11, and I think a little example of _how_ to use `enable_if` and SFINAE for this purpose would be more helpful than just a general description.